# Server side render Javascript App with Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, puppeteer

I have a Node.js server and a Javascript app that I want to render server-side.

How can I use Puppeteer to render this JS app into an HTML page and save it for an email, caching, etc.?

Comment: I'm not sure you actually need puppeteer for this. In fact [react comes with built-in support for this](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html)

Comment: Yes you’re referring to static one time through render to string. My use case is a React app that fetches other resources is: weather api service and other assets. Puppeteer helps solve these async loading in a browser context 

Answer (score 0):

I have React applications that I bundle and put in my nodejs server directory for Puppeteer to render and capture some html. Here's me working solution:

Create the following files with their respective content:

```
/assets
  - index.html
  - bundle.js
/render.js
```

```html
<!-- /assets/index.html -->
<html>
    <body>
        This is a test index.html file

        <div id="root"></div>

        <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
// /assets/bundle.js
(() => {
   document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = "The JS bundle loaded!! " + new Date().toISOString()
})()
```

```js
// /render.js

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')

const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
const page = await browser.newPage();

const assetFilePath = path.join(__dirname, "./assets/index.html");

await page.setRequestInterception(true);

page.on("request", interceptedRequest => {
  const url = interceptedRequest.url();

  if (url.startsWith("file://") && !url.match(assetFilePath)) {
    interceptedRequest.respond({
      body: fs.readFileSync(
        path.join(__dirname, "./assets/", url.replace("file://", ""))
      )
    });
  } else {
    interceptedRequest.continue();
  }
});

await page.goto(`file://${assetFilePath}`, {
  waitUntil: "networkidle0"
});

const html = await page.evaluate(() => {
  return document.documentElement.innerHTML;
});

console.log(html);
```

Run `npm install puppeteer`

Run `node render.js`